# Kotlin strange behaviour with chunked, async and await

Tags: kotlin, asynchronous, kotlin-coroutines

I'm doing some code that involves a number of parallel requests in batchs from elements in a list and I'm facing a strange behaviour:

```
import kotlinx.coroutines.*

suspend fun main() {
    coroutineScope {
        val hello = listOf("hello", "world")
        val chunks = hello.chunked(1) {
            async { translate(it.first()) }
        }
        chunks.forEach {
            print(it.await())
        }
    }
}

private fun translate(word: String): String {
    return if(word == "hello") {
        "hola"
    } else {
        "mundo"
    }
}
```

It should display "holamundo" but sometimes this example prints "mundomundo" instead.

I made it available on [Kotlin Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/joFkWgV13) as well.

What I'm missing here?

Comment: Assuming you need to create a collection of translated chunks, note that it is better to use `chunks.awaitAll()` instead of awaiting on each item separately. It is shorter and in the case one of async task fails, `awaitsAll()` fails immediately.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The reason for this behavior is that the code inside `async` is not run immediately. It is only scheduled. The `async` block returns before the lambda is invoked. This is why the `it` inside `async` block always points to the `["world"]` window and hence the final output is "mundomundo".

Take this example:

```kotlin
fun main() {
    runBlocking {
        var a = 1
        val deferred = async {
            println(a)
        }
        a++
        deferred.await()
    }
}
```

[Playground](https://pl.kotl.in/EnrQS4PxX)
In this example the output will be `2` and not `1` because `a++` is processed before the `async` lambda.

**Edit:** As @IR42 pointed out in the comment, the documentation clearly mentions the the list passed to the transform function changes very quickly, so if you want to use it asynchronously you should first make a copy of it.

```kotlin
val chunks = hello.chunked(1) {
    val copy = it.toList()
    async { translate(copy.first()) }
}
```

This code will give you the expected output.

Another solution (thanks to @broot) is to first calculate the entire chunked list and then map it to the list of deferred.

```kotlin
val chunks = hello.chunked(1).map {
    async { translate(it.first()) }
}
```

Comment: From [chunked](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/chunked.html) documentation "Note that the list passed to the transform function is ephemeral and is valid only inside that function. You should not store it or allow it to escape in some way, unless you made a snapshot of it."

Comment: I think comment by @IR42 is more important than the answer itself. It as a normal thing that we invoke `async()` repeatedly using `forEach()`, `map()`, etc. and this is perfectly safe. The problem here is more specific to `chunked()` than to `async()`.

Comment: Another solution, probably more "natural" would be: `chunked(1).map { async { ... } }`.

Comment: @broot Thanks for the suggestion. Edited my answer accordingly.